# cfml transaction commit rollback different transaction

Tags: transactions, rollback, cfml

Is it possible to have a transaction, commit that transaction, have a new transaction and when there is an error in this 2nd transaction, is it then possible to rollback both transactions?

See below:

```
transaction action="begin" {
  transaction action="SetSavepoint" savepoint="sp1";

  try {
      .. do something ...
      transactionCommit();
  }
  catch (any, e) {
     transactionRollback("sp1");
  }
}

transaction action="begin" {
  transaction action="SetSavepoint" savepoint="sp2";

  try {
      .. do something ...
      transactionCommit();
  }
  catch (any, e) {
     transactionRollback("sp1");
     transactionRollback("sp2");
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how CFML works, but you can only have one transaction open at a time. I suspect that once the `transaction action="begin"` block ends, the transaction is commited.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - FWIW, the CFML simply forwards sql commands on to the database for execution. So the behavior is the same as if you issued the same commands ie `begin transaction, rollback, commit,....` directly in the database.

Comment: I found cftransaction to be risky, I have had cases were a cfml server restart / timeout would leave a open transaction open. The cfcatch block would not help in these cases. We now either put our SQL into storedprocedures.  Or directly write out transactions commands using <cfquery> and use the native transaction commands. 

That way the commit, rollback etc code is sent to the SQL Server in one batch ensuring no hung transactions.
For example when using MS-SQL Server you can set savepoints that way.

Answer (score 0):

No. A commit transaction is final. It cannot be rolled back.

Keep in mind, CF's only role is to forward sql commands to your dbms. The database does the rest. So if you have questions about the behavior of a particular sql operation, you should consult your database documentation. For example:

- [SQL Server - COMMIT TRANSACTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190295.aspx)
- [MySQL - START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Already begun to think a transaction was final, after alot of testing i indeed found out that once a transaction is done, it's done..